# Regular Expression - Valid IPv4 excluding multicast addresses and broadcast addresses

Tags: java, regex, ip, ipv4

Im trying to create a regular expression that will check if an IP is valid & usable. We want to exclude those that match multicast address e.g 224.0.0.2 and address such as 0.0.0.0.

The code at present checks anything between a range 0-255 but I can't work out how to implement this in.

My code so far is

```
^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b
```

Any help would be awesome

Comment: It'd be easier by spliting on `.` then test each element.

Comment: What do you mean by splitting on . ? Sorry i'm fairly new to regex

Comment: I mean separate the 4 elements of an IP address.

Comment: You do want an answer in .Net?

Comment: I'm programming in java.

Comment: Sorry Oli, I don't know if Java has (?! ) in its language. I added Java to this post's tags to not get any other .Net developer. GL

Answer (score 0):

It'll be most portable, easiest to write, and easiest to maintain will be to do it in parts.

```
\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b
```

This will only match valid IP addresses plus split each part out for further inspection

```
if (int(group[1]) != 224 and (int(group[1]) != 0 or int(group[2]) != 0 or int(group[3]) != 0 or int(group[4]) != 0) ...
```

Regex isn't so good at "but not" operations.

But if you insist on having it as a single regex, then just enumerate all the valid options.

```
\b(25[0-5]|2[0134][0-9]|22[0-35-9]|1[0-9][0-9]?|[2-9][0-9]|[2-9])
\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b
```

... which isn't perfect because it only tests that the first octet is not 224 or 0.  If you want a full test against 0.0.0.0 then you'll have to reproduce the above 15 times recognizing all combinations where at least one octet is non-zero.

And of course you'll want to *write a test* to ensure you're returning the correct answer for all 4 billion combinations.  Shouldn't take too long to run...  ;-)